# jQuery create multidimensional array from multiple elements

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I make a multidimensional array with structure like this one for each li with class `sl-item`:

```
$imagesList = [
   [1, 123, "<img src=\"/img-src/123.jpg \" />", "/photo/img-123", "image-alt "],
   [2, 452, "<img src=\"/img-src/452.jpg \" />", "/photo/img-452", "image-alt "],
];
```

First should be just number of array, 1,2,3…, second part is the `id` of `li` element, third is the img with img src, fourth is the url from `a` with class `photo-url` and fifth is the img alt.
My structure is the following:

```
<ul class=”sl-img”>
    <li id=”123” class=”sl-item”>
        <a  class=”photo-url” href=”/photo/img-123”>
            <img alt=”image-alt” src=”/img-src/123.jpg” >
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id=”452” class=”sl-item”>
        <a  class=”photo-url” href=”/photo/img-452”>
            <img alt=”image-alt” src=”/img-src/452.jpg” >
        </a>
    </li>
    .....
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you need the number in the array? isn't that covered by the index in the array?

Comment: yes it is covered by index, you are right, that can be left out.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
var result = [];

$('li').each(function(i){
    var $img = $(this).find('img');
    result.push([i+1, this.id, $img[0], $img.prop('src'), $img.prop('alt')]);
});

console.log(result);
```

I tried with `map()` at first, but it seems to flatten the array.

http://jsfiddle.net/EX6Dt/